# What's the default value for a quantum register?

Tags: programming, qiskit, experimental-realization

I've just started to learn Quantum computing with Qiskit: I'm reading the [Qiskit](https://qiskit.org/) documentation and the book "[Quantum Computing in Practice with Qiskit® and IBM Quantum Experience®](https://www.packtpub.com/product/quantum-computing-in-practice-with-qiskit-and-ibm-quantum-experience/9781838828448)".

In this book, on page 79 we can read: "*..., as we set up our qubit to start as 0, ...*"

Can we set up the start value for a quantum register?

Because I think I have read that they have its default value to 0, and we only can set it to one using the NOT gate.

I have tried to set it to 0 in Quantum Experience and I haven't found how to do it, and also with Python and I haven't found it.

Comment: IBM Q qubits are always set to zero state. Here you can see how to prepare any arbitrary initial state: https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/15807/how-does-one-create-the-unitary-sending-0-rangle-into-a-target-quantum-state/15813#15813

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the seven [DiVincenzo's criteria](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DiVincenzo%27s_criteria) is the  ability to initialize the state of the qubits to a simple fiducial state. In most quantum hardware, this is taken to be the state $|0\rangle^{\otimes n} = \overbrace{|0\rangle \otimes |0\rangle \otimes \cdots \otimes |0\rangle}^{n \ times} = |0 0 \cdots 0\rangle$.

If you create a quantum circuit on IBM hardware and pretty much all other hardware platforms, then the initial state is taken exactly to be this $|0\rangle^{\otimes n} $ state. For example, a 3 qubit circuit will starts out like this:

[image]

Then you can operate on this initial state by applying different quantum gates. For example:

[image]

---

Note that the basis in quantum computing is taken to be $|0\rangle = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$ and $|1\rangle = \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} $. This is known as the computational basis.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do we decide which initial value will have the quantum register or this register will have the same initial value regardless of what we do? I think that "**set up**" means **intentionality**: we do something to set this value to the register.

Comment: Every qubit will start in the initial state $|0\rangle$. You do not need to specify anything. The moment you create a circuit, the initial state of each qubit is in the state $|0\rangle$.

Answer (score 3):

The *default* value for a quantum register depends on the hardware. In the case of most of the IBM hardware, that's $|0\rangle$.

However, Qiskit is hardware agnostic and do not assume an initial state. In order to initialize your circuit, you need to use the instruction `Initialize`. You can initialize with the values $|0\rangle$ (`0`), $|1\rangle$ (`1`), $|+\rangle$ ( `+`), $|-\rangle$ (`-`), $|i\rangle$  (`r`), and $|\mbox{-}i\rangle$ (`l`).

```
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit
from qiskit.extensions.quantum_initializer.initializer import Initialize

circuit = QuantumCircuit(6)
circuit.append(Initialize("10+-lr"), range(6))
circuit.draw()
```

```
     ┌──────────────────────────┐
q_0: ┤0                         ├
     │                          │
q_1: ┤1                         ├
     │                          │
q_2: ┤2                         ├
     │  initialize(1,0,+,-,l,r) │
q_3: ┤3                         ├
     │                          │
q_4: ┤4                         ├
     │                          │
q_5: ┤5                         ├
     └──────────────────────────┘
```

Notice that the instruction `Initialize`, when decomposed, starts with a `Reset` instruction (`|0>`):

```
circuit.decompose().draw()
```

```
          ┌───┐ ┌───┐ 
q_0: ─|0>─┤ H ├─┤ S ├─
          ├───┤┌┴───┴┐
q_1: ─|0>─┤ H ├┤ SDG ├
          ├───┤└┬───┬┘
q_2: ─|0>─┤ X ├─┤ H ├─
          ├───┤ └───┘ 
q_3: ─|0>─┤ H ├───────
          └───┘       
q_4: ─|0>─────────────
          ┌───┐       
q_5: ─|0>─┤ X ├───────
          └───┘
```

Comment: Wow! There are a lot of things to learn! Thanks a lot!